# PHP Session variable not accessible

Tags: php, session

I am having a problem in accessing a session variable.I have one page lets say test.php, when i use `print_r($_SESSION)` here, it prints all the session data.But when i use `<a href="test2.php">Redirect</a>` then i am unable to access session data on `test2.php` i-e print_r prints empty array, even though i have `session_start()` at the top of my script.

Then i tried `header("Location: test2.php")` and now session data is accessible.
But i want the page to be redirected on onClick of a button.

Please help ..

Comment: Is your PHP session id in a cookie or supposed to be in the url variable? Can you post the code of both pages?

Comment: Please add a `var_dump($_COOKIES);` next to the `print_r` of the `$_SESSION`. Compare the differences.

Comment: @hakre `var_dump($_COOKIES);` print NULL

Comment: @claude please read my comment below for code ....

Comment: Please try again without the S, `$_COOKIE`, my fault. It should display the session id cookie. If not, the session got lost and `session_start` will create a new session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the path `http://localhost/project/orders.php` in href then i changed it to just `orders.php` and it worked

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have session_start(); in the head of both files and you're not browsing in a private browsing mode.

Comment: Have you got cookies enabled in your browser?

Comment: Could you provide samples of both files?

session_start(); should be at the top of test1 and test2 (and any other files you wish to have an active session in).

Comment: `TEST1.php`  `session_start();`  `$order_id = $_GET['order_id'];`  `<a href="orders.php?order_id=<?php echo $enc->encrypt($order_id);?>">Purchase</a>`

Comment: `orders.php`    `session_start(); print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: Where is $_SESSION['user_id'] being set initially? It looks like you're using a framework. It may store sessions differently.

Comment: No i am not using FW.UserID is set in the login page when user successfully logs in

Comment: And there is a session_start() on the login page too? This is strange.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, accessing with http or https or http://www can make the difference of variables in session being accessed or not. Please browse through all in order to be certain, as sometimes saved urls are with www whereas the session is created with simple http. It matters in session accessibility.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. I don't think that the session is tied to the protocol that is being used